# Gradle Kotlin DSL equivalent for Groovy DSL compilerArgs for compileJava

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

For the Gradle Java plugin, what is the Kotlin DSL equivalent for the following Groovy DSL?

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ['-Xdoclint:all,-missing', '-Xlint:all']
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(arrayOf("-parameters", "-Xdoclint:none", "-Xlint:all"))
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)