# Gradle Kotlin DSL - Cannot access 'verbose': it is private in 'CompileOptions'

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, groovy

I am trying to set the `verbose` flag/option to true in the gradle build script (Kotlin DSL).

Gradle throws error that this property is private and not accessible in Kotlin DSL. The same thing works in Groovy DSL though.

###### Groovy DSL (working)

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}

tasks.named("compileJava") {
    options.verbose = true
}
```

###### Kotlin DSL (not-working)

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}

tasks.named<JavaCompile>("compileJava") {
    options.verbose = true
}
```

###### Error

```
Script compilation error:

  Line 32:     options.verbose = true;
                       ^ Cannot access 'verbose': it is private in 'CompileOptions'

1 error
```

I am sure I am missing something. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CompileOptions](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/language-java/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/compile/CompileOptions.java) has a setter for `verbose`, so this will work

```
tasks.named<JavaCompile>("compileJava") {
    options.setVerbose(true)
}
```

It is also possible to set the flag via property:

```
tasks.named<JavaCompile>("compileJava") {
    options.isVerbose = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is `private` for Kotlin DSL and not for Groovy DSL, but found an alternative using `compilerArgs` from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50524229/8822610)

```
tasks.named<JavaCompile>("compileJava") {
    val compilerArgs = options.compilerArgs
    compilerArgs.add("-verbose")
}
```

This, to me, feels a bit low-level since we are directly updating the compiler arguments instead of using objects/maps to set them. Will wait for someone to post a better solution (if it exists).